# No me funciona un while para crear Modal de bootstrap en PHP

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Pasa que intento con el while traer todos los productos de una base de datos y este funciona bien en el sentido de que replica los botones y cuadrados para mostrar cada producto, pero no funciona la misma logica para crear un Modal de Bootstrap.

Cuando apreto algún botón azul me debería desplegar el modal con el numero respectivo, pero no es asi.

[image: Se ve bien aquí]

[image: Pero al apretar el botón azul en cualquiera de ellos, me sale el numero "7" que corresponde al primer producto]

```
<?php
            include ("../PHP/conexion.php");
            $query = "SELECT * FROM imagenes";
            $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
            while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $id=$row['id'];
                echo $id;
        ?>
            <div class="card card_productos m-1 p-0">
                <img src="data:image/*;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen'])?>" class="card-img-top " alt="..." >
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row['nombre']?></h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal"><?php echo $row['id'];?></button>
                        
                    <a href="../PHP/eliminar.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                    <?php echo row['id'];?> //AQUI EL PROBLEMA------------------           
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php        
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: TODOS LOS MODAL DEBEN TENER ID DISTINTOS

Comment: @John eso he intentado con el echo row['id'] en las id de los modal, pero extrañamente no me funciona así, pero si funciona si coloca una constante por ejemplo $nombre="hola", aun así no logra mi objetivo.

Comment: id no puede ser un numero asi como la clase no puede ser un numero usa un string compuesto, "texto_".$row['id']

Comment: Te recomiendo tener un único modal (fuera del while) y cargar dentro del mismo lo que requieras usando JS.